# Resolving submodule paths in git

Tags: git, shell

I'm trying to create helper to select desired git submodule. Very simple thing:

```
    modules=`git submodule | sed 's/.* \(.*\) (.*/\1/'`;
    select var in $modules; do 
        echo $var; 
        break; 
    done
```

My repo structure looks like this:

```
    /
    |-dir1
    |   |-submodule1
    |-dir2
        |-submodule1
```

When I save script above as executable file and run it from shell, I see correct relative paths to submodules, like this:

```
    $ cd dir1
    $ git-submodule-select
    1) submodule1
    2) ../dir2/submodule2
    #?
```

But, if I try to save same command as a git alias in my .gitconfig, it always shows paths relative to repo's root, no matter where I am:

```
    [alias]
        subs = "!f() { \
            modules=`git submodule | sed 's/.* \\(.*\\) (.*/\\1/'`; \
            select var in $modules; do  \
                echo $var; \
                break;  \
            done; \
        }; f"

    $ cd dir1
    $ git subs

    1) dir1/submodule1
    2) dir2/submodule2
    #?
```

Why this happens? I need paths, relative to my current location - can it be done through git aliases at all? Or I must use only global functions?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for git aliases has what you need in it.

> alias.*
>
> Command aliases for the git command wrapper - e.g. after defining "alias.last = cat-file commit HEAD", the invocation "git last" is equivalent to "git cat-file commit HEAD". To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing Git commands are ignored. Arguments are split by spaces, the usual shell quoting and escaping is supported. A quote pair or a backslash can be used to quote them.
>
> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command. For example, defining "alias.new = !gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD", the invocation "git new" is equivalent to running the shell command "gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD". Note that shell commands will be executed from the top-level directory of a repository, which may not necessarily be the current directory. GIT_PREFIX is set as returned by running git rev-parse --show-prefix from the original current directory. See git-rev-parse.

Specifically that last bit about where the shell commands will be executed from and the `GIT_PREFIX` variable.